# How refresh a Jtable on java by jbuton

Tags: java, swing, jtable, updates

I'have `Arrayliste` `unecasetable` , I'm create a `Jtable` by this liste

```
    class Modes extends DefaultTableModel{
        public Modes(){
         addColumn("");
         addColumn("Les Symptomes");
         addCol

umn("La maladie");

             System.out.println("mefgoudabrahim20.ExpertInterface1.<init>()");
 //            addRow(new Object []{"","",""});
//             ClassLaBaseDeConnaissance e = new ClassLaBaseDeConnaissance();
//             SBC.Regle.add(e);
//             SBC.unecasetable.add(new UneCaseTable(0));



                    for(int i = 0 ; i<= SBC.Regle.size()-1;i++){
             addRow(new Object[]{false,"", SBC.Regle.get(i).fait});
                        //  SBC.unecasetable.add(new UneCaseTable(0));
           // addRow(new Object[]{"","",""});
            //SBC.Regle.add(new ClassLaBaseDeConnaissance());
            SBC.unecasetable.add(new UneCaseTable(row));    
                    row++;
                    }

            }



    }
```

and i'm creating this functions :

the default `model` :

```
    class Modes extends DefaultTableModel{
        public Modes(){
         addColumn("");
         addColumn("Les Symptomes");
         addColumn("La maladie");



        System.out.println("mefgoudabrahim20.ExpertInterface1.<init>()");
 //            addRow(new Object []{"","",""});
//             ClassLaBaseDeConnaissance e = new ClassLaBaseDeConnaissance();
//             SBC.Regle.add(e);
//             SBC.unecasetable.add(new UneCaseTable(0));



                    for(int i = 0 ; i<= SBC.Regle.size()-1;i++){
             addRow(new Object[]{false,"", SBC.Regle.get(i).fait});
                        //  SBC.unecasetable.add(new UneCaseTable(0));
           // addRow(new Object[]{"","",""});
            //SBC.Regle.add(new ClassLaBaseDeConnaissance());
            SBC.unecasetable.add(new UneCaseTable(row));    
                    row++;
                    }

            }



        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {

             if (columnIndex==0) 
                      return Boolean.class;

            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

                         @Override
           public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

            if(column ==2 )
            {
                 SBC.Regle.get(row).fait = aValue.toString() ;
            } 

         }

        }
```

I will to create a `Button` for update my `TABLE`  .

Comment: I honestly have no idea what it is you're trying to do or what the problem your having is

Comment: I'm sure you don't write code with random formatting of the text, so don't expect us to read code with random formatting. Use either tabs or spaces in your code and be consistent.